# Do I have to install Openssl 1.0.1g in usr/local/lib64 to overwrite usr/lib64 one? (CentOS 6.4, heartbleed issue)

Tags: linux, centos, openssl, heartbleed

I am using a VPS, I need to upgrade openssl with the new package in consequence of the heartbleed vulnerability issue. 
But I am a newbie in managing server, I need to know if I am getting this right :
Does the folder usr/local/lib64 will locally overwrite usr/lib64?
Like if I install the openssl 1.0.1g package in here, is it going to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use `yum update` on the system.

Comment: hey thanks. I did it, it worked, but now I have 1.0.1e version, is that enough?

Comment: @user2123664 - Verify CentOS back ported the fix into that version.

Comment: `openssl version -a` displays build date of your openssl, check if it's around 2014/04/08